# Javascript and HTML in Android

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have tried to run this Javascript code in Android Studio but I got an error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :", source: file:///android_asset/Smart.html (64)

**Here is my code :**

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>
    <script src="highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
     <!--<style type="text/css">-->
    <!--${demo.css}-->
<!--</style>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
   var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">' +
                'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                pointStart: 1940,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'USA',
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369,
640,
                1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104]
        }, {
            name: 'USSR/Russia',
            data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
                4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
                15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
                33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
                21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000]
        }]
    };
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong ? Can anyone please help me ?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/area-basic/.............i m using the code of following link..can anyone tell me how can i run this code in android

Comment: Which is line #64?

Comment: series: [{........this is 64th line

Comment: you are referencing other scripts in this script. are they also available in the asset folder ?

Comment: yess...all scripts  are in assest folder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing `<script>` tag. You also missed the `renderTo` argument.
Check this code,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>
    <script src="highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Missing script tag here -->
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    window.onload = function () {
       var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container', // renderTo was missing
                type: 'area'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'US and USSR nuclear stockpiles'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">' +
                    'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
            },
            xAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Nuclear weapon states'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    pointStart: 1940,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 2,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
              },
            series: [{
                name: 'USA',
                data: [null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
                    1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                    27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                    26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                    24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                    22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                    10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104]
            }, {
                name: 'USSR/Russia',
                data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                    5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
                    4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
                    15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
                    33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                    35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
                    21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000]
            }]
        }
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i added this..but same output

Comment: only with this change...i got the output